Gradient of energy in ADAPT-VQE algorithm
In the ADAPT-VQE algorithm (see https://arxiv.org/pdf/1812.11173), step (5) involves measuring commutators of the Hamiltonian with each operator in the operator pool to get the gradient of the energy with regards to an operator parameter:
$\frac{\partial E^{(n)}}{\partial\theta_N} = \langle \psi^{(n)} | [\hat{H},\hat{A}_N] | \psi^{(n)} \rangle $
I am unsure how this equality comes about; Why is the gradient of the energy with regards to $\theta_N$ equal to expectation value of that commutator?
Attempt at solution:
Starting from the stationary Schrödinger equation for $\psi^{(n)}$, we take a inner product from the left with $\psi^{(n)}$:
$ \hat{H}|\psi^{(n)}\rangle = E^{(n)}|\psi^{(n)}\rangle \Rightarrow \langle\psi^{(n)}|\hat{H}|\psi^{(n)}\rangle = E^{(n)}$
Take the derivate with regards to $\theta_N$:
$\frac{\partial E^{(n)}}{\partial\theta_N} = \frac{\partial}{\partial\theta_N}\langle\psi^{(n)}|\hat{H}|\psi^{(n)}\rangle$
If the right-hand side can somehow be rewritten further, one would be able to get to the desired result, but I am unsure how to proceed from here.

Lets do the math on an example with only a single $A$.
$E =\langle \psi | H |\psi \rangle =\langle\psi_0| e^{-\theta A } H e^{\theta A} |\psi_0\rangle $ where $ |\psi\rangle =e^{\theta A} |\psi_0 \rangle $
$\frac{\partial E}{\partial\theta} = \langle\psi_0| e^{-\theta A } (-A)H e^{\theta A} |\psi_0\rangle  + \langle\psi_0| e^{-\theta A } H(A) e^{\theta A} |\psi_0\rangle $
$\frac{\partial E}{\partial\theta} = \langle\psi_0| e^{-\theta A } [HA-AH]e^{\theta A} |\psi_0\rangle $
$\frac{\partial E}{\partial\theta} = \langle\psi|  [H,A]|\psi\rangle $
The same argument can be made with multiple $A$ and you have $|\psi\rangle = e^{\sum_i \theta_i A_i} |\psi_0\rangle $ but it looks like they are using $|\psi\rangle = \prod_i e^{\theta_i A_i} |\psi_0\rangle $, so they might need an extra condition that all the $A_i$ commute.

thank you so much for the answer! I did not realise the operators are of the form $\exp{\theta \hat{A}}$.
